# Using pcolor or pcolormesh with data in mesh center (polar plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a polar plot of a temperature field.

I used pcolor/pcolormesh but both of them make an interpolation between each corners of the mesh.

Thus, I am looking for a simple way to center the meshes on the center of my data with a mesh color corresponding to the data only in the center of these meshes.

Finally, It would be very nice if I could have polar meshes and not rectangular meshes.

Thanks for your help.